# Makefile generate dependency automatically does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, dependencies

I have four cpp files and so many `.h` files. I expect my make file generates the appropriate `.d` file for each `.cpp` file and compiles them to `.o` and then links them. Could some one tell me what is wrong with this code? it does not work in the way that it should.

Btw, I am beginner in makefile! Please do not link to somewhere with hard explanation for highly experts.

> $make
>
> g++ -c -g -Wall -Wconversion -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -std=c++11 -MD -MP -MF ./bin/obj/app/sim_rhs.d -o bin/obj/app/sim_rhs.o  app/sim_rhs.cpp
>
> app/sim_rhs.cpp:49:1: fatal error: opening dependency file ./bin/obj/app/sim_rhs.d: No such file or directory
>
> }
>
> ^
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> make: *** [bin/obj/app/sim_rhs.o] Error 1

Cpp Files:

```
main.cpp
app/sim_rhs.cpp
app/sim_mids.cpp
app/sim_outputs.cpp
```

Makefile

```
SOURCES := main.cpp  app/sim_rhs.cpp app/sim_mids.cpp app/sim_outputs.cpp
OUTDIR:= ./out
BINDIR:= ./bin
OBJDIR:= ./bin/obj
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
DEPFILES:= $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -c -g -Wall -Wconversion -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -std=c++11 -MD -MP

LIBS:= -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system 

# default
%:: $(BINDIR)/sim

# Link the executable
$(BINDIR)/sim: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

run:
    $(BINDIR)/sim

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF $(OBJDIR)/$*.d -o $@  $<

-include $(DEPFILES)
```

Please avoid duplicate suggestion as I have an existing code. I do not want any other person's makefile template.

Comment: I believe this question is duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582936/makefile-depency-issue

Comment: @RonThompson, I have an existing code. Could you tell me which part of it is wrong?

Comment: I don't think any part of it is wrong.  I just think the makefile may need to be edited, like in the answer to that question.  It looks like his solution was to create the necessary directory in the makefile.

Comment: @RonThompson all output directories are fine. it is not the case.

Comment: You're right, sorry I overlooked that line in your file.  I'm looking at it now.

Comment: @RonThompson could you please remove the duplication mark?

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to remove flags? or I would, sorry.

Comment: For what it's worth, I still think it's a directory issue. It's looking in ./bin/obj/app/ and not finding the .d file there. Meaning either it shouldn't be looking there, or it should and the file isn't being placed there.

Comment: @RonThompson What is your idea to fix it. How should I drop `app` from name the path?

Comment: I'm thinking it's something in that add prefix line. I've never used that, so I don't understand what it's doing. Sorry, I thought it would be an easier fix.  It looks like it's adding ./bin/obj in front of app/*.d. I think if you remove the add prefix section and let it create the .d files in the same directory as the .cpp files it may work.

Comment: Either that or edit the dependencies line to reference sources instead of objects, so you can still keep the objects separated.